# Sharing an instance specific variable across projects in a WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI which receives an ID as a part of the request. I instantiate a logger, which adds this ID as a part of the log.

```
public class A
{
    public void method(string log, string ID)
    {
        Logger.Log(log,ID); //A static reference to the Logger
    }
}
```

But, this approach requires me to pass the ID through each and every method as a parameter, which might make the code look slightly cumbersome.

```
methodA(parameters,ID);
public void methodA(someParameters, string ID)
{
    methodB(params,ID);
    Logger.Log(log,ID);
}
public void methodB(someParameters, string ID)
{
    methodB(params,ID);
    Logger.Log(log,ID);
}
...
...
```

But, I can't make it a static variable either, because each request will have a separate ID. Is there some way I can make the code better? Like, defining a shared variable which can be accessed across all the projects. Or is DependencyInjection the only way?

Comment: So the webapi method calls the methodA() and methodB()? What is the flow from WebApi?

Comment: are you using WCF?

Comment: @Vinoth The WebApi calls MethodA() and MethodA calls MethodB() and so on. So, for each call, we would have to keep passing the ID as a parameter.

Comment: @Sid No, only a native WebAPI without WCF.

Comment: have you thought about using a `Singleton` ?

Comment: Singleton would have the same value across all the requests, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dependency injection is not the only way but it is the right one.

1. Define the logging service:

   ```
   public interface ILoggingService 
   { 
      void Log(string log, string id); 

      void Log(string log); 
   }

   public class LoggingService : ILoggingService
   {
       private string id;

       public void Log(string log, string id) 
       {
           this.id = id;
       }

       public void Log(string log) => Log(log, id);
   }
   ```
2. Inject it in a request scope (using [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) just as example):

   ```
   Bind<ILoggingService>().To<LoggingService>().InScope(_ => _.Request);
   ```

Comment: +1 I was about to write the same thing, Anyways @Andriy maybe you should point out that you are using `Ninject`

Comment: @Sid You are right. Just indicated the usage of `Ninject` for example in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, One of the principle of REST is to be stateless. that is it should not store any data for sharing between the requests. the approach you have mentioned in the question is the right one. however if you really want to do this, you can create a cookie when the first request comes, the rest of the requests will have the cookie and you can get the id from there.

https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-cookies

Comment: Yes, but I did not want to share the information across requests. Instead, I wanted to create some shared space across the different modules without having to pass them as params. Seems like DI is the way to go then.